Freeness assumption in the proof of the Deduction Theorem in Lambek-Scott
In the book "Introduction to higher order categorical logic" by Lambek and Scott they prove the Deduction theorem for the cases of conjunction, positive, intuitionistic and classical calculus (proposition 2.1), in the following form:
Thm. Given any proof $\varphi(x): B \rightarrow C$ in $\mathcal{L}(x)$, where $x : T \rightarrow A$ is the assumption, there exists a proof $\kappa_{x \in A} \varphi(x) : B \rightarrow C$ in $\mathcal{L}$ (i.e. without assumptions).
Here, $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the "deduction system" in question in their terminology, i.e. an oriented graph together with a finite number of chosen objects (propositions), arrows (proofs) and composition operations on arrows (deduction rules).
Now the problem is that the proofs is defined inductively on the "length" of a proof. However, I don't see how you can define that unless you assume that $\mathcal{L}$ is the free such calculus (conjunction, positive, or otherwise), i.e. unless you assume that you can somehow think of the arrows as formal expressions.
So my question is, is the theorem as stated (without assumption of freeness) valid?
